# как обезопасить пароль или ключ активации программы от декомпиляции на .net

Tags: c#, .net, декомпиляция

если писать программу на C# то программу очень легко декомпилровать тем же .NET Reflector если по копаться можно найти ключ или пароль для входа в программу если же ключ будет на ftp сервере или в базе данных то можно перехватить данные снифером.

Comment: Тема очень широкая, и старая, как... нечто очень старое. Для защиты от декомпиляции есть различные обфускаторы + можно написать нативный модуль на C++ или Delphi и вот уже его обфусцировать VMProtect'ом - это жуть. Для защиты от снифферов есть шифрование трафика и возможен детект запущенных снифферов, установленного прокси в системе. Можно предпринять что-то совершенно иное, например, просто не хранить секретный функционал в программе.

Comment: достаточно безопасно хранить в программе *ключи* в виде хэшей [например SHA256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx) из них -- вводимые пользователем значения также преобразуем в хэш SHA256 и сравниваем (для одинаковых исходных значений их хэши также будут равны); если же при декомпилляции взломщик узнает хэш, получить из него оригинальный *ключ* ему будет трудновато :)

Comment: конфиденциальную информацию можно хранить в SecureString, а ключ и пароль генерировать динамически на основании аппаратной конфигурации (https://github.com/MatthewKing/DeviceId) и сохраняемой каким-то образом информации об активации и сверять эти данные с тем, что на сервере в случайные промежутки времени (день, неделя, месяц).

Answer (score 2):

Модуль аутентификации можно сделать нативным, собирающим идентификатор инстанса с хэша каких-нибудь данных, вроде MAC-адреса (если есть ограничение на количество инстансов). На основе этих данных можно сгенерировать ключи и обмениваться информацией с сервером. Таким образом:

1. нативный модуль будет сложнее сломать
2. исключается воровство ключей через MITM (ассиметричное шифрование)

Само собой, права FTP/БД-юзера зарезаются до необходимых.